# Is there a way to document side-effects of a method using the .NET XML documentation tags in the source?

Tags: .net, documentation, xml-comments, xml-documentation

Is there a way to document side-effects of a method using the .NET XML documentation tags in the source?

If there is no tag specifically for this, what is the recommended way to document side-effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  tag. Microsoft documents sideeffects cautions under remark section. you can follow the same rule.

Here is the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: It's strange that there is no tag specifically for something as important as this.